# How to return multiple array from a webassembly function call?

Tags: javascript, arrays, webassembly

I'm looking for a way to return multiples array with variable sizes from a webAssembly function call. At first, I thought about using a struct with several arrays and returning it, but I could find anyway and any information to receive the struct in the javascript. I don't know if that is possible. If not, what other alternative do I have?

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible by only using WebAssembly, because there is no concept of "a dynamic array" in the type system of WebAssembly. WebAssembly supports only basic types, like i32, i64, f32, and so on.

Other languages that have arrays and compile to WebAssembly often use some basic type (i32 or i64) to signify the offset of the first byte of the array, but that is just one of the ways to implement it.

You can return an array of basic types as a result, due to the [multi-value returns](https://github.com/WebAssembly/multi-value) (a proposal already merged into the current version of the specification), but that is as far as you can go.